# What design pattern correspond to described solution

Tags: design-patterns

The solution below very similar to the "handlers" concept, but still struggling to find correspondent pattern or (combination of patterns). Instead of words will try to describe through the simple C# code:

```
interface IHandler
{
    bool CanHandle(string requestType);
    void Handle(object request);
}

IHandler[] handlers = new IHandler[] {h1, h2, ...., hN};

void Handle(string requestType, object request)
{
    foreach(var handler in handlers)
    {
        if(handler.CanHandle(requestType)) 
        {
            handler.Handle(request);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to emphasize here: **request** object passed to only one or zero handlers.
Doing that way I want to make sure that other handlers will not corrupt the state of **request**.

PS. Another option is to refactor that code into a more pattern-oriented solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably making a mistake in thinking that a handler should be able to decide whether or not it can handle a request based solely on the `requestType` string.

If it is your intent to give the early handlers a chance to decide how the request is handled before considering the later handlers, consider switching to a more standard [chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern.  It does that without presuming to know how each handler will make its decision.

If you really expect the handling decision to be based solely on `requestType`, then you should build a `Map<String, IHandler>` during initialization, and then just look up the correct handler instead of walking a chain for every request.

Comment: I have a feeling that I am doing wrong (or not in a good way) here.

The main difference from the "chain of responsibilities" two things:
1) Each handler does not know anything about other handlers. 2) request object should not walk through all handlers due to safety reasons.

The idea behind the original question is: Third parties can provide their own handler implementation and they can decide to process requestType or not. And only in case if handler responds with a 'true' request object passed to that handler.